# Dynamicaly expanding table with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a table gui that returns the user selected row and col number. this is what I have so far:

### HTML

```
<div id="target">
  <table>

  </table>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#target td {
  min-width: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  min-height: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td.selected {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

### Javascript

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  createTable(5, 5);
});

function createTable(rows, cols) {
  var minRows = 5,
    minCols = 5;

  rows = (rows < minRows) ? minRows : rows;
  cols = (cols < minCols) ? minCols : cols;
  var $table = $("<table><tbody></tbody></table>");

  for (var i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
    var $tr = $("<tr />");
    for (var j = 1; j <= cols; j++) {
      var $td = $("<td />");
      $tr.append($td);
    }
    $table.append($tr);
  }

  $("#target table").replaceWith($table);
  bind();
}

function bind() {
  $("table td").hover(function() {
    var minCols = 5,
      minRows = 5;

    var col = $(this).index();
    var row = $(this).parent().index();

    createTable(row + 2, col + 2);

    $("table td").removeClass("selected");
    var $trs = $("table tr");
    $trs.slice(0, row + 1).each(function(i, tr) {
      if (i > row)
        return false;
      $(tr).find("td").slice(0, col + 1).addClass("selected");
    });
  });
  $("#target").mouseleave(function() {
    console.log("left");
    createTable(5, 5);
  });
  $("table").on("click", "td", function() {
    var col = $(this).index();
    var row = $(this).parent().index();
    console.log(row + ", " + col);
  });
}
```

### Fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/shirandror/efr7dkxL/

So I'm stuck with two problems with this code. First, when a TD is clicked, the click event doesn't fire. And second, when the mouse leave the wrapping div, the mouseleave event is called hundreds of times. What am I missing here?

Comment: use  `$('#target').off('mouseleave');` just before
  `$("#target").on('mouseleave',function() {` like this   `$('#target').off('mouseleave');
  $("#target").on('mouseleave',function() {`

Comment: That indeed solved the problem with the mouseleave. Thank you.

Comment: @RRR you should post your solution as an answer so OP can accept your answer.

Comment: @Toby Allen: RRR answered just one of the two questions I had, there is still the clicked td issue.

Comment: That is why stackoverflow has a 1 question per post policy

Comment: Should I post a new question with the updated code than?

Comment: @ShiranDror the other prob is not with event delegation but the event getting trapped inside `hover` forever even when you click `hover` get triggered there is something wrong in your  `bind()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `$("table td").hover(function() {` to `$("table td").on("mouseenter", function() {`

kindly check: https://jsfiddle.net/efr7dkxL/12/

**jQuery**

```
var minCols = 5,
    minRows = 5;

$(document).ready(function() {
    createTable(5, 5);
});

function createTable(rows, cols) {

    rows = (rows < minRows) ? minRows : rows;
    cols = (cols < minCols) ? minCols : cols;
    var $table = $("<table><tbody></tbody></table>");

    for (var i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
        var $tr = $("<tr />");
        for (var j = 1; j <= cols; j++) {
            var $td = $("<td></td>");

            $tr.append($td);
        }
        $table.append($tr);
    }

    $("#target table").replaceWith($table);

    bind();
}

function bind() {

    $("table td").on("mouseenter", function() {

        var col = $(this).index();
        var row = $(this).parent().index();

        var $trs = $("table tr");
        var $tds = $trs.first().children("td");
        if (($trs.length != (row + 2) && ((row + 2) >= minRows)) || ($tds.length != (col + 2) && ((col + 2) >= minCols))) {
            createTable(row + 2, col + 2);
        }
        $trs = $("table tr");
        $("table td").removeClass("selected");

        $trs.slice(0, row + 1).each(function(i, tr) {
            if (i > row)
                return false;
            $(tr).find("td").slice(0, col + 1).addClass("selected");
        });

    });
    $("#target").off("mouseleave");
    $("#target").mouseleave(function() {
        createTable(5, 5);
    });

}

$(document).on("click", "table td", function() {
    var col = $(this).index();
    var row = $(this).parent().index();
    console.log((row + 1) + "," + (col + 1));
    $('.msg').text('ROW: ' + (row + 1) + ' and COL: ' + (col + 1));
});
```